# Mandatory field icon Display 3 times

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a simple webform for adding a candidate. In my *Add Candidate* form, I am using 3 buttons - two buttons for saving a data, and one button for cancel. On two buttons two different validations groups are used. when I am clicking on first button, proper validation group called and when I am clicking on second button then also it works fine. However, when I am entering a wrong value in textbox then it will show 2 validation messages but I want to show only one message like below:

> [image]

Markup:

```
<TextBox ID="txtDateofBirth" runat="server" Width="120" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" onblur="javascript: ValidateDate(this);" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event, this);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must enter a valid Date Of Birth"
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDateofBirth" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Validations">!</asp:CompareValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpDateOfBirth" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Entered Date Of Birth must be greater than 20 years"
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDateofBirth" Operator="LessThanEqual" ValueToCompare='<%# DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(7300)) %>' Type="Date" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Validations">!</asp:CompareValidator>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDateofBirth" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Date of Birth"
                            ValidationGroup="Validations" ControlToValidate="txtDateofBirth" ForeColor="#CC0000" Display="Dynamic">!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDateofBirth" TabIndex="4" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.png" 
                            AlternateText="Click here to display Calendar" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" />
                        <ajaxcontrol:CalendarExtender ID="CEDateofBirth" runat="server" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"  
                            Format="MM/dd/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDateofBirth"
                            PopupButtonID="imgDateofBirth">
                        </ajaxcontrol:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you refer following tutorial for validation group http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2012/11/validationgroups-in-aspnet-part-50.html
Hope it will work for you!

Comment: thanks kishor for replying. i seen these video i know the rules of validations but when i am selecting a date from date control that time showing these message

Comment: until we will not see your code. I don't think anyone can help you more!